# Visual Basic disappearing textbox?

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I've looked all over the web for an answer to this, and been unable to replicate the bug myself, and somehow the textbox is appearing to be transparent and unable to be clicked; however it seems that if you set the "Text =" property to have a message in it, the textbox works fine.

I've looked at the properties and the code multiple times, nothing seems to be off. There's no calling of the textbox to be transparent, and nothing I've seen that would stop it from accepting user input.

The... "broken" code is:

```
Public Class GuessingGame

    Const MIN As Integer = 1
    Const MAX As Integer = 50

    Private Sub btnCheckGuess_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCheckGuess.Click
        Randomize()
        Static secretNumber As Integer = Int((MAX - MIN + 1) * Rnd() + MIN)
        Static Count = 0
        Dim guess As Integer

        Count = Count + 1
        guess = Val(Me.txtPlayerGuess.Text)
        If guess < MIN Or guess > MAX Then              'invalid guess
            MessageBox.Show("Guess out of range")
        ElseIf guess = secretNumber Then
            Me.lblMessage.Text = "You guessed it!"      'correct
            MessageBox.Show(Count)
        Else
            Call GiveHint(secretNumber, guess)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtPlayerGuess_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        'Clear the current answer when the user begins to type a new value
        Me.lblMessage.Text = Nothing
    End Sub

    Private Sub GiveHint(firstNum As Integer, ByVal secondNum As Integer)
        If firstNum > secondNum Then
            MessageBox.Show("Too low.")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Too high.")
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Anyone have any ideas as to what is causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Setting `Text = Nothing` may be the problem. Try `Text = String.Empty`.

Comment: are you sure you are talking about a textbox?  the only place one appears is as: `guess = Val(Me.txtPlayerGuess.Text)` and nothing is being SET there...and dont use `Val` get used to using `Convert.ToInt32` or `TryParse`, you will be glad you did.

Comment: You don't need to `Call` in VB.NET. Also try to get into habit of using `Option Explicit` where possible.